# Are questions to review markdown on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, markdown

Markdown itself is almost a (very) small subset of HTML, which is rendered as such. We use markdown on many places, including on the whole Stack Exchange network and Github. Sometimes, it is a good idea to ask for a review on the quality of the markdown.

Are those questions on-topic here?

---

In my opinion, they are since they have a defined structure with specific parameters. And since questions about HTML are on-topic, that made me think about it.

Comment: Are you talking about "Markup Languages"? if you are talking about XML/HTML/XSLT and other markup languages, I believe that those are already on-topic.

Comment: @Malachi I honestly don't know. But I'm talking about the language we use to write the comments, questions and answers here. Much like BBcode.

Comment: What kind of review do you expect? "How to make look better for the people who read the rendered markdown?" As far as I know, there's not really much possibility to produce *the same thing in a cleaner way*. If you change the markdown, the output will look differently.

Comment: It would be easier to have an opinion on this if you would have an example question that you could include in this meta question.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg If I include a question and it is off-topic, I will watch my reputation go down the drain while I see the question being flooded by downvotes. And yet another closed question.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Your reputation is not affected by downvotes on meta. Also, if you would mean the main site, deleting a question restores any reputation losses.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Isn't that kind-of cheating?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel There's nothing cheating about removing a bad question. Also, I meant that you include the example question itself here on meta. Not post the question on the main site and link to it here.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg There is no example question as of now. It just clicked on my mind and I decided to ask. But I can make a mock-up code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BBCode can vary depending on the site that host the BB, so I would say no, because

1. There is no set standard for BBCode/MarkDown/etc.
2. Syntax for Markdown is rendered and doesn't actually do any work like an XSLT file or a parser

If we are talking about specifically Stack Exchange markdown, that would only be on topic for Meta sites, because the markdown is different for each site, ie MathJax is different for each site, the delimiter for it changes depending on the site.

Comment: I am talking about The Stack Exchange markdown (Github markdown is somewhat compatible with it). BBcode was an'example' to express better what I mean. I just don't get why "`we aren't going to say explicitly Stack Exchange markdown`". And why post on the specific site meta?

Comment: [There is a standard for Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). Though most sites extend/modify it in some way and so [there is an attempt to standardize it further](http://commonmark.org/).

Comment: There being a standard or not is not an argument either way. There are many languages out there, used daily by loads of people that haven't been formally standardized (yet), think of Perl, PHP (changed since 2014, standard not finished yet), Python all lack a formal standard (AFAIK)